# Multiple hasMany relationships of the same type on a model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working with a class which has multiple hasMany relationships of the same type, but with different attribute names.  For example:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  sunday: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time'),
  monday: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time'),
  tuesday: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time'),
  wednesday: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time'),
  thursday: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time'),
  friday: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time'),
  saturday: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time'),
  ...
```

This might represent something like, "on Monday, employee X is scheduled to work 9am-12pm (one `scheduled-time` instance), and again from 1pm-5pm (another `scheduled-time` instance)."  For each day of the week, an employee could have zero, one, or many scheduled times.

The other side of the relationship might look like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  start_time: DS.attr('string'),
  end_time: DS.attr('string'),
  schedule: DS.belongsTo('schedule'),
  ...
```

However, Ember data doesn't seem to allow this, and says that I need to explicitly state the inverse of the `belongsTo` (as detailed here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/relationships/).  Here's where I think my data model is broken: I can't think of any logical way to say that a given scheduled-time belongs to any given day of the week.  Is this data model broken?  I have a feeling that instead of organizing all of the `scheduled-time`s under individual days of the week, they should really belong collectively under a single attribute, and perhaps the days of the week would be computed properties which did some filtering instead.

Is this type of relationship possible, or should I do some refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

A `shift` is a `scheduled-time`, and an employee can `hasMany` `shifts`. The fact that `shift A` is on a Sunday, and `shift B` is also on a Sunday, but `shift C` is on a Tuesday doesn't make a difference.

```
// models/employee.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  shifts: DS.hasMany('scheduled-time')
});
```

Comment: Right, this is kind of what I was talking about at the end, with organizing all of the `scheduled-time`s underneath a single attribute, instead of under attributes by day-of-the-week.  It seems like it's going to be the way to go.